# execution reverted. ZkSyncEra, CallContract

Tags: go, blockchain

When I try to call a contract method in ZkSyncEra, I get `execution reverted`

This is a pull contract of version 3 of the pancakeswap exchange, but it works with any contract, the abi corresponds to reality and the example is reproducible on any contract, the method really exists and it can be checked in the scanner

My go.mod file

```
module etron

go 1.21.4


require (
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum v1.13.6
)
```

Minimal Example

```
package tests

import (
    "context"
    "testing"

    _pkgWeb3 "etron/pkg/web3"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)


func TestCalling(t *testing.T) {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.era.zksync.io/")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    abi, err := _pkgWeb3.LoadAbi("Abi.json") 
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    to := common.HexToAddress("0x141853f48B5Fe6cC6Cc792417dff59B9009D796d")

    callData, err := abi.Pack("slot0")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    msg := ethereum.CallMsg{
        To:   &to,
        Data: callData,
    }

    result, err := client.CallContract(context.TODO(), msg, nil)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _ = result
}
```

What am I doing wrong please help